# NodeJS TCP Socket does not show client hostname information

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

lets say I've created a simple node.js TCP Socket server as follows.

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.end("goodbye\n");
});
// listen on port 80, like a webserver would, and configured to accept connections to multiple hosts, ie test.example.com, sdfsdfsdf.example.com, example2.com. 
server.listen(80, function() {
  address = server.address();
  console.log("opened server on %j", address);
});

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //log('connection data', socket);
    log('CONNECTED SOCKET DATA', socket.address());
    log('CONNECTED LOCAL, %s:%s', socket.localAddress, socket.localPort);
    log('CONNECTED %s:%s', socket.remoteAddress, socket.remotePort);

    //How do I find the server hostname that the client connected to?
    // eg test.example.com or example2.com
});
```

Once a tcp `connection` is made, I want to parse the hostname that the client attempted to connect to. However the `socket` does not seem to have this information.

The following is what I got when I ran the previous code (removed ip addresses)

```
CONNECTED SOCKET DATA { port: 80, family: 2, address: '[SERVER IP ADDRESS]' }
CONNECTED LOCAL, undefined:undefined
CONNECTED [CLIENT IP ADDRESS]:13263
```

I've gone through the nodejs [socket documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_class_net_socket) but I cant find anything related to host name. The documentation actually says that the `socket.localAddress` will be an IP Address, with makes it useless in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is not available at the TCP layer. You need to look at the `Host` header at the `HTTP` layer when a request arrives. This will be available as `req.headers.host` when a request arrives. http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_message_headers

Also based on your comment, trying to run a non-HTTP server on port 80 is asking for trouble. You are going to get connections from web spiders and botnets all the time, so make sure your program properly handles HTTP clients connecting and disconnects them or perhaps sends an HTTP error message.

Joe is correct in the comment that if you are not using HTTP, your custom protocol will need to transmit the "virtual host" name from the client to the server in the first packet/header message of your custom protocol.

Comment: unfortunately I'm only using the TCP layer to transfer data. I have a tcp socket server and multiple tcp socket clients. I just need to determine which hostname socket each of the clients are connecting to.

Comment: It's not there at the TCP layer.  You will have to incorporate it into your communications done over TCP (e.g. sent as part of your initial message from client->server)