# Reading/Setting socket header information [Node.js]

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am currently working on a project that involves a few layers of TCP communication. For the purpose of this project, most of the TCP communication that needs to be implemented is user validation and forwarding streams to their corresponding endpoints. One problem I keep running into is that there is no way to access any header information from incoming sockets that I know of or can find in the `net` documentation.

I have found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745745/nodejs-tcp-socket-does-not-show-client-hostname-information) with no results on this. I've also found a [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket) that can make connections with raw sockets, but making connections is only half the battle here.

Is there another module, native or not, that solves this? Or is there a way to access the necessary layer through the `net` implementation?

**Edit 1 (for clarity):**

I'm trying to make a router for multiple RTMP servers. Connections will come in, and depending on header information like the path and query string, they either be rejected because their credentials were invalid, or they will be forwarded to the relevant server.

I am using `node-media-server` as my server base. For the router, there currently isn't much code, because what I want to do and implement relies on this.

```
const testNet = net.createServer((socket)=>{

    /*
     *  TODO: validate credentials given by socket, reject if invalid
     */

    /*
     *  TODO: Create ID for socket and create a header that 
     *        reflects this new id and the new endpoint
     */

    let newConnection = net.createConnection({port:1937, host:host}, () => {
        newConnection.on('end', () => {
            socket.end();
            newConnection.end();
        });
    });
    socket.pipe(newConnection);
    newConnection.pipe(socket);
    socket.on('end', () => {
        newConnection.end();
        socket.end();
    });
}).listen(1935,host,()
```

I'm still learning the bridge between RTMP and TCP, so I understand if there are still some missing gaps with what I've presented. I hope that this was enough information to clear up what I want to do, and what I want to know.

Comment: It's unclear (to me ) exactly what you're trying to accomplish or what precisely the problem is?  What does "access header information" mean?  Exactly what are you trying to do?  Please show actual code or actual protocol or both.

Comment: You will certainly need to use not only C or C++ for this but also raw sockets. No Javascript solution is possible.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated the post to include more information

Comment: @user207421 Darn, I was hoping someone knew of a node implemented server solution using raw sockets. Welp, guess it's time to learn raw sockets

Comment: There is no "bridge between RTMP and TCP".  RTMP is a binary protocol that runs on top of TCP.  Here's the [specification](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf).  I can't tell what you're really trying to accomplish to have any idea how to advise further.

Comment: @user207421 - Why do you say that it's not possible in nodejs?  Nodejs has raw sockets with the `net` library.  It just appears that the OP is going to have to unpack the RTMP protocol to understand what's in each packet and therefore what the router should do with it or somehow use the node-media-server to do that for them.